# BeanFactory DesignPattern?

Tags: spring

Are bean factory implementations like  xmlbeanfactory and application context example sof FactoryMethod pattern or Abstracr factory pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them.
Read to learn what are FactoryMethod and AbstractFactory. Spring's BeanFactory has nothing to do with the aim of them.

Comment: i have read both i.e FactoryMethod and AbstractFactory.I have read on some site it follows the factory pattern. To me it looks closer to abstractfactory as Xmlbeanfactory also capable of creating the related objects.

Comment: It is a factory, that's all.  In high level it doesn't fall into any of the factories in GoF patterns.  It is obviously not Factory Method.  It doesn't shows any characteristic of Abstract Factory.  I just wanna point out, even it is "factory", it doesn't means it will fall into any factory pattern of GoF design pattern.